# angular: Async process from .run is not over in .controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, deferred

I have an issue with the logics in my ionic/angular app. I need some javascript best-practice advice on this.

In the `.run`, I asynchronously retrieve a database from a server. When it's done I write an array containing information in the `localStorage`:

```
 .run([ ....

  var promiseUpdateProDB = updateProDB.get();
  promiseUpdateProDB.then(
          function(prodata) {
              var prodata = sessionService.get('prodata');

              var imagesUrls = imagesService.manage(prodata);
              // console.log('imagesUrls in app.js :');
              // console.log(imagesUrls);
              sessionService.persist('imagesUrls', imagesUrls);
          },
          function(error) {});
```

Then, in the .controller('AppCtrl', ...., which is the controller of my side menu, I need this information written in the localStorage :

app.js:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
...
```

controllers.js:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ....
....
$scope.imagesUrls = sessionService.get('imagesUrls');
$scope.getImgPathProfileModal = function(str) {
    str = $filter('nospace')($filter('lowercase')(str));
    str = str + ".png";
    return $scope.imagesUrls[str];
}
```

but at this time, the asynchronous process is not finished, and `$scope.imagesUrls` is null....

Can you help me figure out a clean/best practices/robust way to do this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You can use resolve parameter for the state and retrieve the database data in resolving function.

Comment: with angular we can't access `.state()` I think. Could you please show me some code ? And should I use the `$rootscope` for this ?